# How to create a slicable torch.Dataset with an underlying pd.Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-learning, pytorch

This is a bit long, but is the shortest I could do to describe this problem.
The code I provide is for conceptual understanding, and I request a conceptual answer. Providing full code makes no sense here.

---

### Problem statement:

I have ~100 dataframes, each with ~100000 rows. Each describe a time series.

I want to create a Dataset called `FullDataset` for all of these Dataframes together, such that as a whole, I will be able to easily slice it, and sample from it by some global indexing. I also need to be able to split it to train, val, test.

### Example usages:

1. `torch.utils.data.DataLoader(full_dataset, batch_size=8, num_workers=1)`
2. Split to train, val, test *WITH NO PYTHONIC LOOP FOR THE ROWS*.

What I have now uses a Pythonic loop for slicing, which makes it indefeasibly slow [not posing full code for question simplicity]:

```
def __getitem__(self, index: Union[int, slice]):
    if isinstance(index, int):
        if index < 0: index += len(self._in_features_df)
        if index < 0 or index > len(self): raise IndexError(f"The index {index} is out of range")

        data_item = self._in_features_df.iloc[index * self.frames_per_pd_sample: (index + 1) * self.frames_per_pd_sample, :].values.real
        data_item = data_item.T

        label_item = self._out_features_df.iloc[index * self.frames_per_pd_sample: (index + 1) * self.frames_per_pd_sample, :]

        return data_item, label_item  # channels as dim 0
    elif isinstance(index, slice):
        return [self[ii] for ii in range(*index.indices(len(self)))]
```

When using this mechanism for splitting to train, val, test, this is too slow:

```
train = full_dataset[:train_size]  # this is a very long python loop
all_val = full_dataset[train_size:]   # this is a very long python loop
```

Notice this data splitting scheme is easy to explain, but I want to be able to do more complicated ones, based on different slicing.

For example, If I wanted to slice the start and end of each of the 100 Dataframes, each sample having more than a single row (say 10 rows).

Example code for this use case:

```
train = []
all_val = []

case_lengths = full_dataset.case_lengths
case_start_ind = 0
case_end_ind = 0  # non inclusive
for case_len in case_lengths:
    case_end_ind += case_len

    case_data = full_dataset[case_start_ind:case_end_ind]
    case_train_size = int(self._config.train_size * case_len)
    case_train = case_data[:case_train_size]  # slow
    case_all_val = case_data[case_train_size:]  # slow

    train.extend(case_train) # slow
    all_val.extend(case_all_val) # slow

train_loader = DataLoader(train, batch_size=8, num_workers=1)
```

---

### Summary

- I am looking for a way to keep the slicing functionality, but without
  the list comprehension part which is slow.
- Keeping everything as Dataframes doesn't work, because `Dataloader`
  doesn't know how to work with pd.Dataframe directly, and because I
  have to help it anyway in case samples are not single rows, and this
  is best done in the single Dataset's `__getitem__`
- Maybe there is a way to split a dataset without explicitly sampling
  it beforehand, and passing THAT to a Dataloader?

---

[This](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/49440#issuecomment-789402075) is an ongoing discussion on the topic, but I wonder how this should be solved before torch version 3.0